# Does the k-clique problem became easier on sparse graphs?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, clique

Some definitions, just to not create confusion:

1. A *sparse graph* is a graph that contains a number of edges less or equal than the number of vertices.
2. In *$k$-clique problem* we are given a graph and an integer $k$, and the task is to decide whether the graph contains a $k$-clique.

I think that even if we have a sparse graph, nothing changes for the $k$-clique problem (it always has complexity $O(n^k)$ if $k$ is less than number of vertices and it has complexity $O(n^n)$ if $k$ is equal to the number of vertices), but I'm not so sure about this.

Is a $k$-clique easier to find if the graph is sparse?

Comment: If $k$ is a constant, then there is no sense in asymptotically comparing it to the number of vertices. In any case, if $k$ equals the number of vertices then the question translates to "is the given graph a clique?", which is solvable in linear time, which does not come near $n^n$.

Comment: I would say that this question would be better if the _sparsity_ definition was strengthened to say that every subgraph $G'$ has $|E(G')| \leq c \cdot |V(G')|$ for some constant $c \ll n$. This would remove the trivial case where you can simply add $n^2$ isolated vertices, and it would also give a positive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, you can always add $\binom{n}{2}$ new vertices not connected to anything to get a new sparse graph $G'$ with the same clique number. So assuming that the graph is sparse doesn't make it much easier to find its largest clique. In particular, determining whether a sparse graph has a clique of given size (which is part of the input) is NP-complete.

Comment: ok so you're basically saying that it doesn't change anything if the graph is G or is G', right?

Comment: It changes a lot of things, but not the clique number (i.e., the size of the largest clique).

Comment: i accept your answer as the best one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let me not completely agree with Yuval's answer.

Indeed, in some sense sparsity does make a maximum clique problem easier, and this is proved also by solving it on real-life networks. Usually benchmarks for a maximum clique are pretty dense. And here is why.

1. If it is known an integer $k$ that is a lower bound of the clique number (or the number itself, but we are looking for a clique), then one can reduce the graph to $(k-1)$-core, that is the graph where each node has a degree at least $k-1$. The resulting graph might be considerably smaller in size and thus, for example, IP solver might get a huge boost. How to reduce: delete all vertices with degree smaller than $k-1$ until those exist.
2. If you look at sparsity not from the density perspective, but from the [degeneracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)) perspective, things are even more formalized. Usually we say that graph is "sparse" when its degeneracy is low. And there exists FPT algorithms with running time around $O^{*}(2^{d/4})$ where $d$ is graph's degeneracy (here big-O star means that the algorithm depends polynomially on the graph size).

Conclusively, the maximum clique problem is immensely easier on sparse instances, though it still remains $\mathcal{NP}$-Complete (but FPT on degeneracy).